# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - incredibly slow TCP/IP connection time over ethernet

Tags: networking, 18.04, kernel, internet, ethernet

This problem has recently appeared - last few days. New connections are taking up to 60 seconds. Once connected the up and down speeds are ok IF the requested service hasn't timed out.

I thought I read that this might be related to a kernel upgrade from 5.3 to 5.4, but can't find that post

Output of `uname -a`

`Linux paul-HP-15-Notebook-PC 5.4.0-132-generic #148~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 24 20:41:14 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Output of `sudo lshw | grep -A 15 "network"`

```
   *-network
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
        logical name: enp8s0
        version: 07
        serial: 34:64:a9:7f:ee:aa
        size: 100Mbit/s
        capacity: 100Mbit/s
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.0.123 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
        resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b2600000-b2600fff memory:b2400000-b2403fff
```

The computer is a 2014 HP laptop

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it appears to have been a fault with the switch between laptop and router